# tendo una duda sobre count php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7, php5

como verán en la imagen esta es un campo de una tabla de usuario llamada puntos pero quiero que se cuente no los registros si no toda esa cantidad guardada por parte del usuario, entonces como se dan cuenta estoy utilizando una función llamada count.

[image]

esta parte del codigo es que no tengo la suficiente capacidad de hacer que se cuente todos esos datos.
ejemplo

13
22
22
24
28

que me muestre todo ese total que serian 109

```
$points =  $db->query("SELECT count(1) FROM login where points=points+1");
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso no necesitas el COUNT(), lo que necesitas es el SUM().
COUNT lo que hace es contar el total de registros que extrae según la condición en tu caso 5 (5 registros).

Debes aplicar SUM(), que lo que hace es sumar los valores de una columna, $points =  $db->query("SELECT SUM(points) FROM login where points=points+1");

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ERES MI HEROE B)